# Json call in joomla 2.5 component

Tags: json, angularjs, joomla

I'm making a joomla 2.5 component and i trying to set in model or controller (what's the most appropriate ?) a json response of my DB request (for later get the json with angularJS).

Here's my model (with DB response):

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.modelList' );


class MediastoreModelList extends JModelList
{
    function getListQuery()
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id, type, designation', 'marque', 'prix');
        $query->from('produits');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

My empty controller:

```
<?PHP
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class MediastoreController extends JController
{
}
```

My view

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view' );


class MediastoreViewList extends JView
{

    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->items = $this->get('items');

        parent::display($tpl);
    }

}
```

and my template

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHTML::script('media/com_mediastore/js/angular.min.js');
JHTML::script('media/com_mediastore/js/app.js');
?>

<?php 
echo $this->items;
?>
<div class="content">
    <p>Nothing</p>
</div>
```

How can i do that ?

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

Comment: What do you mean how can I do that? Is it not working? Do you get an error? Do you don't know where to place the files?

Comment: Actually, i can get a json with echo json_encode( $this->items ); in my view.
But how to call a service in my angular app with this response ? in a new controller ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make a stand alone angular application?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late .....

Hi I am working on something similar.

In your views (sitepart) add an other file called view.raw.php.

You can browse to this file by appending 'format=raw' at the end of the url.

For example: if your component view page in the browser is 'http://test.com/test( IF SEF is on ) then after appending th url shoul be like this

http://test.com/test?format=raw and in case SEF is not on the use & instead of ?

You can use this URL in the angularjs for http.get service.

In view.raw.php file make sure you just echo the results rather than parent::display($tpl);.

This did work for me.

PS: I am using angualrjs too but want to use the component with many menu items and the url keeps changing so am stuck on that part.

Hope this solves your issue.

Regards,
Jai